# Error loading CNN/Daily Mail dataset from HuggingFace

Tags: huggingface-datasets

I'm new to AI, and NLP in particular.

In my task, I need to load CNN/Daily Mail dataset from HuggingFace datasets.
I was running this on Google Colab and suddenly encountered this error.

[image]

I have no idea why it happened. Could anyone help me with this? Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CNN/DailyMail dataset is hosted on Google Drive, which limits the number of downloads. You probably exceeded Google Drive's quota for this file, you'll need to try again later (the quota is reset once a day).